# How to plot an optimized route between multiple markers in MapBox Android Studio

Tags: java, android, mapbox

I am trying to implement an Android Studio App using MapBox that lets the user select multiple waypoints on the map and then plots the optimized route that goes through each of the user selected waypoints and returns back to the start point.

I have two functions in my code that puts the marker and plots the route.

Marker Function:

```java
@Override
public void onMapClick(@NonNull LatLng point) {
    // Drop a marker wherever the user taps
        
    destinationMarker = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(point));

    destinationPosition = Point.fromLngLat(point.getLongitude(), point.getLatitude());
    originPosition = Point.fromLngLat(originLocation.getLongitude(), originLocation.getLatitude());

    startButton.setEnabled(true);
    startButton.setBackgroundResource(R.color.mapboxBlue);

    getRoute(originPosition, destinationPosition);
}
```

Route Function:

```java
private void getRoute(Point origin, Point destination) { // Route creation function
    NavigationRoute.builder()
            .accessToken(Mapbox.getAccessToken())
            .origin(origin)
            .destination(destination)
            .build()
            .getRoute(new Callback<DirectionsResponse>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<DirectionsResponse> call, Response<DirectionsResponse> response) {
                    // Make sure that we got a response
                    if (response.body() == null) { // If there is no response
                        Log.e(TAG, "No routes found, check user and access token");
                        return;
                    }
                    else if (response.body().routes().size() == 0) { // If there is a response but there is no route
                        Log.e(TAG, "No routes found");
                        return;
                    }

                    // Now we have at least 1 route
                    DirectionsRoute currentRoute = response.body().routes().get(0); // Getting the best route

                    if (navigationMapRoute != null) { // If there is already a route, remove it
                        navigationMapRoute.removeRoute();
                    }
                    else { // If there is no route, create one
                        navigationMapRoute = new NavigationMapRoute(null, mapView, map);
                    }

                    navigationMapRoute.addRoute(currentRoute);
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<DirectionsResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                    // If route creation is unsuccessful
                    Log.e(TAG, "Error:" + t.getMessage()); // Logging the error message
                }
            });
}
```

Currently the app manages to put all the markers on user's on screen tap, however, route creation only occurs between the last marker and the original position of the user. How can I plot an optimized route that starts from the starting location, goes through every marker put down by the user and returns back to the starting location?

[Current Behavior of the App](https://i.stack.imgur.com/715uO.png)

Edit:

I tried to store locations of all markers in a list (List waypoints) I edited my route creation and marker adder functions. Here are the updated versions:

Marker Function

```java
public void onMapClick(@NonNull LatLng point) {
    // Drop a marker wherever the user taps

    destinationMarker = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(point));

    destinationPosition = Point.fromLngLat(point.getLongitude(), point.getLatitude());
    originPosition = Point.fromLngLat(originLocation.getLongitude(), originLocation.getLatitude());

    if (waypoints.size() == 0) { // If the list is empty, add the current location
        waypoints.add(originPosition);
    }

    waypoints.add(destinationPosition); // Adding the marker location to the list

    startButton.setEnabled(true);
    startButton.setBackgroundResource(R.color.mapboxBlue);

    routeButton.setEnabled(true);
    routeButton.setBackgroundResource(R.color.mapboxBlue);

    getListRoute(waypoints);
}
```

Route Function:

```java
private void getListRoute(List<Point> list) {
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i+=2) {
        NavigationRoute.builder()
                .accessToken(Mapbox.getAccessToken())
                .origin(list.get(i))
                .destination(list.get(i+1))
                .build()
                .getRoute(new Callback<DirectionsResponse>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call<DirectionsResponse> call, Response<DirectionsResponse> response) {
                        // Make sure that we got a response
                        if (response.body() == null) { // If there is no response
                            Log.e(TAG, "No routes found, check user and access token");
                            return;
                        }
                        else if (response.body().routes().size() == 0) { // If there is a response but there is no route
                            Log.e(TAG, "No routes found");
                            return;
                        }

                        // Now we have at least 1 route
                        DirectionsRoute currentRoute = response.body().routes().get(0); // Getting the best route

                        if (navigationMapRoute == null) { // If there is no route, create one
                            navigationMapRoute = new NavigationMapRoute(null, mapView, map);
                        }

                        navigationMapRoute.addRoute(currentRoute);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call<DirectionsResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                        // If route creation is unsuccessful
                        Log.e(TAG, "Error:" + t.getMessage()); // Logging the error message
                    }
                });

    }
}
```

I tried to get all the marker locations from the list when a button is clicked. Then plotting the route between them (not optimized) However, the behavior of the app did not change. It still plots a route between the last two markers.

**Edit For David Wasser**
Thank you again for your answer. I solved the problem by creating a variable to keep the route builder. Here is the updated version of the function:
(The changes were done on first 9 lines of the code)

```java
private void getRoute(List<Point> list) {
    NavigationRoute.Builder builder = NavigationRoute.builder()  // Initializing the route builder
            .accessToken(Mapbox.getAccessToken())
            .origin(list.get(0)) // Since we are creating a route with the same start and end points
            .destination(list.get(0)) // Both origin and destination is user's current location
            .profile(DirectionsCriteria.PROFILE_DRIVING); // Default profile allows up to 3 waypoints, thus updating the profile to allow up to 23 waypoints

    for (int i = 1; i < list.size(); i++) { // Adding all the waypoints as pitstops to the route
        builder.addWaypoint(list.get(i));
    }

    builder.build() // Building the route
            .getRoute(new Callback<DirectionsResponse>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<DirectionsResponse> call, Response<DirectionsResponse> response) {
                    // Make sure that we got a response
                    if (response.body() == null) { // If there is no response
                        Log.e(TAG, "No routes found, check user and access token");
                        return;
                    }
                    else if (response.body().routes().size() == 0) { // If there is a response but there is no route
                        Log.e(TAG, "No routes found");
                        return;
                    }

                    // Now we have at least 1 route
                    DirectionsRoute currentRoute = response.body().routes().get(0); // Getting the best route
                    route = currentRoute; // Extracting the route to a variable initialized in MainActivity

                    if (navigationMapRoute != null) { // If there is already a route, remove it
                        navigationMapRoute.removeRoute();
                    }
                    else { // If there is no route, create one
                        navigationMapRoute = new NavigationMapRoute(null, mapView, map);
                    }

                    navigationMapRoute.addRoute(currentRoute);
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<DirectionsResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                    // If route creation is unsuccessful
                    Log.e(TAG, "Error:" + t.getMessage()); // Logging the error message
                }
            });
}
```

Comment: Removed `android-studio` tag. That tag is for problems/issues related to the Android Studio product. Your question has nothing to do with Android Studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't make a loop and call `getRoute()` multiple times. You should call `getRoute()` once and pass it all of the points. You set the origin and destination as you have done (in this case `destination` should be the last point in the list). All the intermediate points are set by calling `addWaypoint()`.

If you want to return to the start point then you should set the `destination` = `origin`.

Comment: Hey @David Wasser, thank you for your answer. The problem is that the waypoints are chosen by the user therefore, although I have all the location info of the markers I will not know how many markers there will be. Hence, I will not be able to hard code it. Is there a way to add all the locations in the List as waypoints to the getRoute() function without knowing how many markers exist?

Comment: I don't understand your problem. You have the waypoints already in a list. Just loop through the list and call `addWaypoint()` on the `NavigationRoute.Builder` for each waypoint.

Comment: I get the idea however, I don't understand the syntax. Where should I put the loop in the function?

Comment: Ok, I solved my problem. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: I'm glad you solved it. Can you post the code you ended up using? I'm curious. Just edit your question and add your new code at the end. Thanks!

Comment: Updated. Thank you again for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

What I need is that the navigation started with the optimized route, I do not know if it is related to this, if you follow the documentation of the optimization API, you already have it

Comment: This is not an answer. If you have a question ask it by creating a post. See: [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). But don't post it as an answer to a possibly related question.